# Database C# .NET in VS code

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, .net

I use Visual Studio code. How do I store my variables in a database? Using C#.

Em português :

eu uso o código do Visual Studio. Como eu armazeno as minhas variaveis em um banco de dados? Utilizando C#.

Answer (score -1):

Olá! .NET Framework fornece uma biblioteca de classes chamada [ADO .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/) que provê ferramentas para persistência de dados. Recomendo começar pela documentação oficial da microsoft!